# Get the index of n maximum values in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to get the index and value of the 4 maximum values in each rows. For example, in the following df, in column a, **10, 6, 7, 8** are four maximum values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [10, 2, 3, -1,4,5,6,7,8]
df['id'] = [100, 2, 3, -1,4,5,0,1,2]
df
```

The output which I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nlargest,

```
df.nlargest(4, 'a').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   index   a   id
0      0  10  100
1      8   8    2
2      7   7    1
3      6   6    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the `a` column

```py
out = (df.sort_values('a', ascending=False).iloc[:4]
       .sort_index(ascending=True)
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   index   a   id
0      0  10  100
1      6   6    0
2      7   7    1
3      8   8    2
```